# Selenium IDE - Extract substring from string

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a variable with this string:

```
Total price: 65.09 GBP
```

How do I extract the number **65.09** from this string and store in another variable? P.s: just the number with 2 decimals, don't need the currency after it, also, the value can be anything from 0 to 1 billion, so it could have commas also to separate the numbers.

I saw some other posts regarding this same issue using split with delimiters or substr(), but I could not adapt it to my scenario, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regular expression to extract the number:

```
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>Total price: 65.09 GBP</td>
  <td>v1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>storedVars['v1'].match(/[\d.,]+/)</td>
  <td>v2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>echo</td>
  <td>${v2}</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```